# Scheduling dag runs in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Got a general query on Airflow

Is it possible to have a dag file scheduled based on another dag file's schedule.

For example, if I have 2 dags namely dag1 and dag2. I am trying to see if I can have dag2 run each time dag1 is successful else dag2 does not run. Is this possible in Airflow.

Answer (score 5):

You will want to add a [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py#L34) the end of `dag1` and set the schedule of `dag2` to `None`.

In addition, if you want to handle multiple cases for the output of `dag1`, you can add in a [BranchPythonOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L103) to create multiple paths based on its output. For example, you could set it to either execute the TriggerDagRunOperator on success or Slack you "Warning! Task Failure in DAG1!" with the [SlackAPIPostOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/slack_operator.py#L86) if an error is thrown (or any other logic you want to build in).

If you don't care about multiple outcomes, you could also just use the [ShortCircuitOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/python_operator.py#L137) before the TriggerDagRunOperator to prevent it from running based on the `dag1` output.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You should include a task at the end of dag1 using the [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py). Make sure this task has a [trigger rule](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=trigger#trigger-rules) that will only allow it to run if all other tasks upstream succeed.

The other answer recommends subdags which can have some oddities that make them less than ideal in complex Airflow environments.

Answer (score 4):

The [DAG schedule interval](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#dag-runs) must be defined as one of:

- a cron schedule
- a preset e.g., `'@once'`, `'@hourly'`, etc
- `None`*

*For the null schedule use case, the DAG won't run automatically and must be triggered somehow.

One way to trigger a DAG is to use [SubDAGs](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=subdag#subdags) via the `SubDagOperator`.  I think SubDAGs are probably the best option for your use case given that you want the second DAG to be triggered as a result of the first DAG succeeding.  There's some nuance to SubDAGs as described in the docs.

The SubDAG will automatically run if the task before it succeeds and skip if the task before it fails/skips assuming you're using `ALL_SUCCESS` or `ONE_SUCCESS` as your [trigger rule](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/c7a472ed6b0d8a4720f57ba1140c8cf665757167/airflow/utils/trigger_rule.py#L25).

[This approach is somewhat similar to the [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/3ed25a9459a2a0b26b849b1a3ea7906f26a33707/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py#L34) operator which is another option detailed in @andscoop's answer.]

Another way to trigger a DAG is with an [external trigger](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#external-triggers).  This idea is discussed in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50592573/149428).