# When using ExternalTaskSensor in airflow, is there a way to get the result from the task in the external DAG?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We have a DAG, call it A, which runs. When this DAG is finished we would like to have another DAG, call it B, triggered. We have gotten that to work with `ExternalTaskSensor`, but is there a way for B to read any of the xcom values from A?

I have tried to use

```
{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(dag_id='a dag_id', task_ids='a task_id', key='a key') }}
```

but that returns `None`, so I guess that is only meant to be used between tasks in the same DAG.

Comment: With `TriggerDagRunOperator` you could *provide* your own context as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611039/scheduling-dag-runs-in-airflow

Comment: @tobi6 I noticed that, but then the dependencies would be in the opposite direction of what I would like. I don't want the upstream DAGs to know about the downstream DAGs.

Comment: Is the `execution_date` the same for both the "A" and "B" processes?

Comment: Yes they were @joeb. I’ll give it another go to see if I did something wrong.