# Salesforce connection using Apache-Airflow UI

Tags: amazon-s3, salesforce, airflow

I was trying to follow along the tutorial for Salesforce integration to Redshift on https://www.astronomer.io/guides/salesforce-to-redshift/. I have successfully setup Amazon S3 connection on Apache-Airflow like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774361/7560912). But there is no **Conn Type** of **Salesforce**. [image]

Does anyone know what the steps are to create a Salesforce connection on the Apache-Airflow UI?

Don't know if it helps but my Airflow is installed on an Ubuntu Amazon EC2 environment.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. The trick is to leave the **Conn Type** empty. I started by filling out the **Host**, **Login** and **Password**. Then on **Extra**, I added a dictionary that had my login's [security token](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_security_token.htm&type=0). It will look like the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: hey @HighAbove , how did you manage to leave the ' Conn Type' empty? when I try to do it, the field already contains a default value. 
also, according to Airflow documentation, we should use the 'HTTP' connection.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-salesforce/1.0.0/connections/salesforce.html

thanks

Comment: This response need more information about connection string.